# Error when loading kableExtra in markdown file after updating to R 4.3.0

Tags: r, markdown, kableextra

After updating to R 4.3.0 (on macOS 13.3.1) I get an error message, when compiling a markdown document:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'kableExtra':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
  call:!is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output)&&rmarkdown::metadata$output%in%
  error: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Execution halted
```

Running the individual chunks in R Studio works without error message.

I already re-installed kableExtra with all dependencies.

Comment: According to the R news `Calling && or || with LHS or (if evaluated) RHS of length greater than one is now always an error, with a report of the form

    'length = 4' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`

Comment: It is a known issue, you need to install patched version from github: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/750

Comment: Your "output" section of the YAML for your document includes 3 entries.  Reduce it to one entry and you'll work around the bug in `kableExtra`.

Comment: If installing dev patch does not work, then remove `pdf` from YAML `output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To install the patched version from zx8754's answer above: `devtools::install_github("kupietz/kableExtra")`

Comment: (noting also need to install devtools for us n00bs)

`install.packages("devtools")`