# KableExtra errors on R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) update

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I updated my R today to R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21) and R studio 2023.03.1+446. All of a sudden I can't run rmd script which previously had no issues.

```
Library (knitr, kableExtra)
```

```
df %>% 
  tabyl(milk, show_na=FALSE) %>%  
  rename(" " = "milk", "Freq" = "n", "%" = "percent") %>%
   adorn_totals("row") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(affix_sign = FALSE) %>% 
  knitr::kable(
    format = "latex",
    align = "l",
    linesep = "") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(
      position = "left",
      latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header"),
      stripe_color = "gray!15") %>% 
      row_spec(0, bold = TRUE)
```

Errors:

```
Error in `row_spec()`:
! could not find function "row_spec"
```

Then I removed row_spec from the code. Error again:

```
Error:
! .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'kableExtra', details:
  call: !is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) && rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% 
  error: 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% ...
 2. base::loadNamespace(x)
 3. base (local) runHook(".onLoad", env, package.lib, package)
Execution halted
```

What do these errors mean?

I haven't provided any dummy data because I think this might be an issue related to the R packages and R version, but happy to add data if necessary.

Comment: probably realted to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76118194/error-when-loading-kableextra-in-markdown-file-after-updating-to-r-4-3-0